# Docker Volumes not mounted after host reboot

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I start various docker containers through `docker-compose up -d` and they all have the restart always flags enabled.

When I reboot the host machine (Windows 10 Pro), the containers restart but it appears the volumes are not mounted. I know this because I keep the config files on the mounted volume and the services bring up the initial setup screen when I go to the webpages, plex for example does the starting new server. When I run `docker-compose stop`, and then `docker-compose up -d` they have the volumes mounted and are using the correct config files. Is there a difference between how the containers get started on a restart versus `docker-compose up`?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a satisfactory resolution? I'm encountering the same issue and would like to not have to "using non-host mounted volumes"

Comment: @QuinnWilson I unfortunately did not, I believe I ended up switching to a linux host as it was more stable, but it was over 2 years ago and I have not maintained that setup for quite some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For host-mounted volumes, it's a known problem that the volumes are not available immediately after restart: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/584#issuecomment-286792858

I recommend using non-host mounted volumes or other workarounds.